# Chrome extension: not seeing logs from background console

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am learning the Chrome Extension, following the instructions in https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/. I downloaded the source code from https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/tutorials/getting-started, and installed it to my browser. Things are working well, except that I do not see the console output from the `background.js` (code below).

```
// background.js
let color = '#3aa757';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ color });
  console.log('Default background color set to %cgreen', `color: ${color}`);
});
```

I opened the background console from the link in extension, and tried to toggle the extension on and off, but the console is always empty (see screenshot below). What did I miss here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The output is lost when the worker is terminated, which happens after 30 seconds of its inactivity by default, see https://crbug.com/1277708. Meanwhile you can open devtools for the worker and keep it open, which will keep the worker running.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you elaborate how to "open devtools for the worker and keep it open"?

Comment: Like you already did, but this time don't close it.